# Can I include Microsoft's debugger tools in my commercial product?

Tags: open-source

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/index
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/usbview

For Microsoft's free tools in general, and specifically UsbView (given the code is open source), can I alter the code, built it, and include it my commercial product to use?

I can't give the license agreement for any of the items above, so I'm wondering if it's ok to redistribute.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because legal questions are off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because legal questions are off topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the github repository you linked there is a MS-PL license specified, which states:

> 2. Grant of Rights
>      (A) Copyright Grant- Subject to the terms of this license, including the license conditions and limitations in section 3, **each contributor grants you** a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free copyright **license to reproduce its contribution, prepare derivative works of its contribution, and distribute its contribution or any derivative works that you create**.

Anyway, read it all for yourself and if you are still unsure, ask them directly.